# Error while implementing monitoring in .NET 8 Web API Microservice - : Unable to load Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces

Tags: c#, open-telemetry, .net-8.0

I'm attempting to implement monitoring in my .NET 8 Web API Microservice by following the guidelines provided in this Microsoft Azure documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/opentelemetry-enable?tabs=aspnetcore
. However, when running the application in my local development environment, I encounter the following error:

```
Unhandled exception
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have ensured that I've followed the steps outlined in the documentation accurately, but I'm still facing this issue. How can I resolve this error and successfully implement monitoring in my application?

Additional Details:

.NET version: 8.0
Development environment: Local machine
Relevant code snippets or configuration settings can be provided upon request.

Comment: Csn you please share your .csproj file (or ideally full [mre])?

Comment: You shouldn't really even need Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces in .net 8, unless something in the chain is referencing netstandard - but: do you have a package reference to that package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installation of Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces 8.0.0.0 library from nuget package will ressolve the issue.

Regards
Vijay

Comment: Thanks @vikram peddapothula for your response. It helped me to fix the issue :)